# jQuery get selected value from selectbox not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I am working on a Woocommerce (WordPress) project and my task is to get selected value from drop-down list when user click on button.

My HTML is:

```
<select name="attribute_taxonomy" id="attribute_taxonomy" class="attribute_taxonomy">
    <option value="">Custom product attribute</option>
    <option value="pa_bedroom">Bedroom</option>
    <option value="pa_bathroom">Bathroom</option>
</select>

<button type="button" class="button button-primary add_attribute">Add</button>
```

and jQuery code is:

```
$('.add_attribute').on('click', function () {
    var selected = $('#attribute_taxonomy option:selected');
    alert(selected.val());
});
```

Unfortunately I am getting blank alert box, not getting anything. But strange is when I create jsFiddle with same HTML & jQuery code I am getting right output.

Why I am not getting anything. Is there any alternate solution? I am not good with jQuery so I will thank-full if someone guide me to fix this issue.

My Sample > [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mananpatel/4QaLS/)

Thanks.

Comment: What is happening instead? are you getting the alert atleast? Are you loading your page dynamically (via ajax)?

Comment: check your developer console (or firebug console) for any errors!

Comment: @Krishna Yes I am getting alert box but not getting value. Just empty popup. No I am not using ajax.

Comment: @Saurabh Hi I checked from console and I am getting this error: `Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function` at my code.

Comment: @lumos you should fix that first(check for the file/line number). Error at a place can cause the code at other place to not work.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use:

```
var selected = $('#attribute_taxonomy');
alert( selected.val() );
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the value of the `select` element, not its selected `option`:

```
$('.add_attribute').on('click', function () {
    var selected = $('#attribute_taxonomy');
    alert(selected.val());
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4QaLS/1/).

I'd also tend to prevent the user interacting with the `button` until a choice is made in the `select` element (using the `disabled` (Boolean) property) and *then*, once a choice is made, prevent the user from reselecting what appears to be an `option` label (note this is more complicated than it needs to be, a possibly improved approach will follow). First, the HTML:

```
<!-- select element unchanged -->

<button type="button" class="button button-primary add_attribute" disabled>Add</button>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#attribute_taxonomy').on('change', function(){
    // cache the $(this) jQuery object since we're potentially using it twice:
    var $this = $(this);
    // if there are no disabled options we run the following jQuery:
    if (!$this.find('option:disabled').length) {
        $this
        // find the option that has no value set:
        .find('option[value=""]')
        // set its 'disabled' property to true (to disable it)
        .prop('disabled', true)
        // go back to the original selector ($(this))
        .end()
        // move to the next element (if it's a button element):
        .next()
        // unset its 'disabled' property (to enable it):
        .prop('disabled',false);
    }
});
$('.add_attribute').on('click', function () {
    var selected = $('#attribute_taxonomy');
    alert(selected.val());
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4QaLS/2/).

A slightly better approach (to my mind) is to use HTML, and its elements, properly; using an `optgroup` to associate the relevant `option` elements, with a `label` attribute set to explain the contents of that group:

```
<select name="attribute_taxonomy" id="attribute_taxonomy" class="attribute_taxonomy">
    <optgroup label="Custom product attribute">
    <option value="pa_bedroom">Bedroom</option>
    <option value="pa_bathroom">Bathroom</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4QaLS/3/).

This approach means that an option, with a value, is always set (though initially to a default unless one of those `option`s is given a `selected` attribute), which means the `button` doesn't need to have its `disabled` property set/unset to prevent accidentally choosing an `option` without a value.

References:

- HTML:

  - [Enabling and disabling form controls](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/attributes-common-to-form-controls.html#enabling-and-disabling-form-controls).
  - [`<optgroup>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup).
- jQuery:

  - [Attribute-equals (`[attribute="value"]`) selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).
  - [`end()`](http://api.jquery.com/end/).
  - [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
  - [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/).
  - [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
  - [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).
  - [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).